# Converting a matrix to a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that is 3*3. I want to convert it to a 6*1 vector in Matlab.
When I use reshape, it has an error:

```
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

So I can't use reshape.
Do you have any suggestion that help me to convert this matrix to a 6*1 vector?

Comment: A 3*3 matrix has 9 elements where a 6*1 vector has 6 elements. How Matlab is supposed to do the conversion? You get the error because of mismatch in sizes. You can convert matrix `A` to a vector using `A(:)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate Mohsen's comment, it sounds like you're asking to do something like this, which would involve losing part of your original matrix.

```
>> A = [1 4 7; 
        2 5 8; 
        3 6 9];

>> B = A(1:6)

B =

     1     2     3     4     5     6

>> B = A(4:9)

B =

     4     5     6     7     8     9

>> B = A([1:3 7:9])

B =

     1     2     3     7     8     9
```